# Changing alpha of UINavigationBar background only?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, uinavigationbar, ios8.2

I'd like to change the alpha of the UINavigationBar in my app without effecting its text and navbar elements.

I do the following in viewDidAppear of my initial view:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5
```

However, that also changes alpha on text and navbar buttons.

I also tried the following with no luck:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1)]
```

Is there a way to just affect the UINavigationBar background alpha?

Comment: Did you find a way of changing just the background and not the text?

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it, is to change the alpha value of the background color when you set the color.

For example:

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 16/255.0, green: 177/255.0, blue: 216/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

Of course you'd change the RGB values, to the color you want it to be.

Comment: Did you try that?  Text is still affected by that alpha value.

Comment: This just sets the background color to an alpha value of 0.5 of the original color you put it as, it has nothing to do with the text. Could you edit your original question, with all the code you use to style your navigation bar. Then I might be able to provide a more precise solution. Or more specifically, the line you use to set the navigationbar's background color

Comment: I don't do anything in code to the navigationbar colors.  So it should be straight forward in that regard.  I'm still not sure how your answer relates since it isn't "background only".

Comment: have you tried adding the line in my answer to your navigationController class? or a viewController that has it? All that line does is set the background Color(bartintColor) of a navigationBar to an RGB value, with an alpha of 0.5.

Comment: yeah. I tried it in my own application. It seems to work fine? And the text, bar items and buttons aren't affected.

Comment: Then why the question mark in your comment?  Unless you can upload that project (dropbox, etc), I don't believe that is what's happening.